# cURL : "Couldn't connect to host"

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have solved that in the past, but I most definitely cannot remember how.

So, I'm trying to fetch a webpage to my server, using a proxy.

**Here is the code :**

```
function curlFile($url,$proxy_ip,$proxy_port,$loginpassw)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);


    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
             echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    print_r(curl_error($ch));

    print_r($data);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

**All it currently outputs is :**

> Curl error: couldn't connect to hostArray ( [url] =>
>   http://www.drkameleon.com [content_type] => [http_code] => 0
>   [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1
>   [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] =>
>   0.007872 [namelookup_time] => 0.007537 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0
>   [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] =>
>   -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 ) couldn't connect to host

So, any ideas? What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver is unable to connect to the proxy

- local security settings on webserver - you didn't say what OS this is running on
- a routing issue on webserver
- firewall policy on proxy

The proxy requires authentication? (You should have got a 4xx response from the proxy - if you've got CLI adccess try running curl from the comand line).

The proxy got a NXDomain on lookup or didn't get the IP address you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the same script on an online PHP platform and see the result. There might be a couple of issues

1. SSL verification problem. If you are making a request to a HTTPS website and if your curl library is not configured to trust the certificates, you'll have a problem. You can download the CA certificate of the other website and point the curl library in that direction.
2. If you are on a university/office network, it might be a firewall issue.
3. Incorrect port configuration.

Run the same script online and see what result you get for [ssl_verify_result]. Also see the HTTP code at which it is pointing at.